# SQL ERROR "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Tags: mysql

This is my query in SQL.

```
SELECT MAX(course_id), sec_id, COUNT(ID) 
FROM (SELECT MAX(course_id), sec_id, COUNT(ID) 
      FROM section 
      NATURAL JOIN takes 
      GROUP BY course_id);
```

When executed, I'm getting this error:

> <"Every derived table must have its own alias">

Comment: your subquery needs to alias the aggregated columns in order for you to use those names in the outer query.  The `select max(course_ID), sec_ID, count(ID)` will error because course_ID and ID don't exist in your subquery. To prove it run the subquery on it's own and look at the column names it gives for cols 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Add an alias to your derived table.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(course_id), 
    sec_id, 
    COUNT(ID) 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            MAX(course_id), 
            sec_id, 
            COUNT(ID) 
        FROM 
            section NATURAL 
            JOIN takes 
        GROUP BY 
            course_id
    ) `A`;
```

Comment: it gives me this error " Unknown column 'A.course_id' in 'field list'

Comment: @AkmaljonUsmonov Sorry. Try the updated query.

Comment: bassxzero, it still gives me this error. (((

Comment: @AkmaljonUsmonov because you need to alias `max(course_ID) as course_ID`  and `count(ID) as ID`